# Create Unique Relationship with additional attributes to the relationship

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am creating a Unique Relationship using the following code:

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(en1:Entity)", "(en2:Entity)")
    .Where((Entity en1) => en1.EntityName == sParentEntity)
    .AndWhere((Entity en2) => en2.EntityName == sChildEntity)
    .CreateUnique("en1-[:sRelationName]->en2")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

For the added relationship, I want to add an attribute named "category" which will take string values.

Is this possible, if so what could be the addition to the above code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the last two lines with this code:

```
.CreateUnique("en1-[:sRelationName { category: {category_name} }]->en2")
.WithParams(new {category_name = "YourCategoryHere"});
.ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it worked. I have a related question. My Intention was sRelationName is a Variable, and I wanted to create a relation in that name. However, its now creating the relation as :sRelation (Which I understand is logical). Can I name the relation from a variable's content ?